# Запуск приложения React и сервером node.js и nginx на домене 3го уровня

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

У меня на сервере запущено приложение express   node.js. Используется nginx
Приложение использует https с бесплатным сертификатом letsencrypt.
URL: https://178.20.42.150.sslip.io

Теперь я хочу подключить домен третьего уровня:
http://criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io

Соответственно он без https, меня это в данный момент устраивает.

Я настроил Nginx:

```
 server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io www.criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                client_max_body_size 100m;
                client_body_timeout 600s;
                client_body_in_file_only clean;
                client_body_buffer_size 16K;
                proxy_connect_timeout 70;
                proxy_send_timeout 90;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                }
        }
```

Открыл порты 3006, 3010 для тестирования.
И у меня запускается мое второе приложение ( React) по
URL: https://178.20.42.150.sslip.io
и проксируется на
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

Но я хочу запускать вместе с приложением Rect и сервер node.js вместе. Я это сделал на совсем другом проекте успешно.  Там при тестировании на локальном PC запускал:

"cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""

client Rect запускался так: "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",

В client/package.json  имелось : "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
А server имел PORT 3000

B все работало нормально.

Но сейчас для домена третьего уровня, что-бы его перенаправить на другое приложение я проксирую в nginx criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io на 3000 port.

После всевозможных экспериментов получаю:

если server запустить на 3000 port, то он не запустится, потому что этот port уже занят client  React. Запускаю сервер на 3010 порту.
Если в client React package.json убрать  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000", то client React приложение запустится ( кстати после манипуляций таких: удалить package-lock.json в client и server и в обоих проектах заново сделать npm install), вот связка client и server не работает. Они работают по отдельности.
Проверял сервер: http://criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io:3010/test   работает.

Если в client React package.json не убирать "proxy": "http://localhost:3000", то client React выведет:
“Invalid Host header”

Консоль при запуске когда в client\package.json:
"proxy": "http://localhost:3010"

Консоль:

```
128|reactc | [0] App
128|reactc | [1]
128|reactc | [1] > example@0.1.0 start /var/www/criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html/client
128|reactc | [1] > set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start
128|reactc | [1]
128|reactc | [0] WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
128|reactc | [0] WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
128|reactc | [0] development mode
128|reactc | [0] App has been started on port 3010...
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /var/www/criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html/client/public
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
128|reactc | [1] Starting the development server...
128|reactc | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | Compiled with warnings.
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | src/components/Chart.js
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
```

Эксперементирую GitHub: https://github.com/illusionoff/reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze

```
Можно ли заставить их работать вместе на доменном имени 3го уровня?
```